# Store SwiftUI functions globally

Tags: swift, function, swiftui

I use ObservableObject to store a @Published property but how can I store a global function that can be used in any view? Can this function include in itself a call of a @Published property?

Comment: Why do you need it to be `@Published`? Can't you just declare it like `func` inside your ObservableObject? And as always please provide some test code.

Comment: It's not something related to a problem that I have that's why I don't need to provide a code. It's just a curiosity on how to declare a function that can be called anywhere in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are some possibilities:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // declare as a property
    let func1: () -> Void = {
        print("func1")
    }

    // declare as a `func`
    func func2() {
        print("func2")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("asd")
            .onAppear(perform: vm.func1)
            // .onAppear(perform: vm.func2)
    }
}
```

You can use an `@EnvironmentObject` to make them available globally.